# SQL One to many query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am having an issue trying to build a query that will do the following:

- Single parent will have a number of child records
- Need to get the status of child records depending on number returned. i.e. 3 status levels are available 1,2 & 3. If all child records returned are 1 then we need to return 1. However, if there are more 2's or 3's then we need to return 2 or 3 instead.
- We only need to look at the last 1 hour of data

Table structure for table 1

```
ID int
parent_name nvarchar(255)
```

Table structure for table 2

```
ID int
parent_id int
status int
dte datetime
```

Comment: Can you post example data ?

Comment: "However, if there are more 2's or 3's then we need to return 2 or 3 instead" what is it? does the count of status values matter? if there are two "2"s and a "3" and a "1" what will be your expected result? the maximum status value or most occured status value?

Comment: As a result of @AndreFeijo answer below we have looked at the whole status issue again and we simply want to highest regardless of count and therefore his answer was just what we needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (I haven't tested it)

```
SELECT MAX(c.status) FROM parent p 
INNER JOIN child c ON p.ID = c.parent_id 
WHERE c.dte > DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: Many thanks that did it, did not even think of using MAX() in that way.